# merge two priority queues

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

```
std::priority_queue<some_type, std::vector<some_type>, some_comparator> A;
std::priority_queue<some_type, std::vector<some_type>, some_comparator> B;
```

How can I merge these priority queues  A and B based on same comparator. I tried to find builtin function but could not find any.

Comment: @BoBTFish: `std::priority_queue` exposes no iterators.

Comment: Push all the elements from one queue into the other?

Comment: @BoBTFish I have already thought of it but the problem is its iterator is not accessible. I cannot do A.begin() or A.end(). That interface is not available.

Comment: I did say I hadn't thought about it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is to simply move objects from one queue to another:

```
while(!B.empty()) {
    A.push(B.top());
    B.pop();
}
```

There might exist a more efficient method, though.

Comment: This looks like my last resort.